# Why did this happen to this character in final fantasy 15? *Spoilers*

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I didn't understand why

> Luna died, Leviathan didn't damage her, the rocky astral came to their defense

so what happened?

Comment: It may help if you were to take our [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour).  It should help you familiarize yourself with our site and how we work.  Voting is an expression of quality, or lack thereof.  Please keep that in mind before responding again.

Comment: You could of just googled "final fantasy 15 luna death"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Final Fantasy Wiki](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Lunafreya_Nox_Fleuret):

> Moments after forging a covenant with the Hydraean, Lunafreya suffers a mortal wound at the hands of Ardyn.

I have never played this game but I think this answers your Question. You can try and find gameplay that shows this event.

Comment: Yup, this is correct. The scene in question is fairly brief, and can be missed if you aren’t paying attention

Comment: you should play it, it's good thanks regardless @Wondercricket adryan was actually not a bad guy, behemot and astrals drove him to madness